# Eigen Jacobi SVD

Tags: c++, eigen3

I am trying to compute SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) with `Eigen`. `C` is a 27x18 matrix with rank 15.

```
JacobiSVD<MatrixXd> svd( C, ComputeFullV | ComputeFullU );
cout << svd.computeU() << endl;
cout << svd.computeV() << endl;

MatrixXd Cp = svd.matrixU() * svd.singularValues().asDiagonal() * svd.matrixV().transpose();
MatrixXd diff = Cp - C;
PRINT_MAT( "diff", diff );
```

`PRINT_MAT` is just a `cout`.
Surprisingly, I see some of the values of diff as very large numbers, something like `4.0733184565807887e+250`.

Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the values of `C`?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mubch99z6jo9k0a/c?dl=0

Comment: On occasional runs I also see `nan`

Comment: What version of Eigen are you using?

Comment: Eigen Version : 3.2.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the sizes of the matrix elements, you'll notice that `svd.matrixU()` is 18x18, `svd.singularValues()` is 18, and `svd.matrixV()` is 27x27. When you write `svd.matrixU() * svd.singularValues().asDiagonal()` the result is a 18x18 matrix which cannot multiply `svd.matrixV()`. You've defined -DNDEBUG which disables bounds checking. The random numbers you saw are what was in memory before allocation. You can get around this using the following code:

```
MatrixXd res(C.rows(), C.cols());
res.setZero();
res.topLeftCorner(C.rows(), C.rows()) = (svd.matrixU() * svd.singularValues().asDiagonal());

MatrixXd Cp = res * svd.matrixV().transpose();
MatrixXd diff = Cp - C;
cout << "diff:\n" << diff.array().abs().sum();
```

As ggael pointed out, you can ask that only the thin matrices be computed, which would look like:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/SVD>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    MatrixXd C;
    C.setRandom(27,18);
    JacobiSVD<MatrixXd> svd( C, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);
    MatrixXd Cp = svd.matrixU() * svd.singularValues().asDiagonal() * svd.matrixV().transpose();
    MatrixXd diff = Cp - C;
    cout << "diff:\n" << diff.array().abs().sum() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The size of `C` is 27x18 so `U` is 27x27 and `V` is 27x18

Comment: No, read the first paragraph of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). The only caveat is that sigma in our case is a vector length 18. The `asDiagonal` method turns it into a 18x18 matrix.

Comment: Note that you can also ask for the thin SVD, in which case the original code should work as V will be 27x18.